# jQuery get grand total from summary Magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, ajax, jquery, grand-total

I'm trying to retrieve the grand total from the summary on the checkout/cart page through jQuery. However, the summary is being loaded with AJAX in some other file which causes my jQuery to not recognize this:

```
$('.grand.totals.incl > .amount').find('.price')
```

I've tried to do it this way:

```
$( document ).ajaxComplete(function() {
                console.log($('.grand.totals.incl > .amount').find('.price'));
            });
```

But this doesn't show anything. How do I retrieve the grand total **after** the AJAX is done loading?

Comment: You'll likely need to access the AJAX yourself, if I get time to take a look I'll provide an answer. Are you adding your JS via require JS?

Comment: Yes, the JS is being added through requirejs